# find_or_create_by with attribute which presence: true in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :email, presence:true
end
```

When I do:

```
@user = User.find_or_create_by(:email => params[:email])
```

I was doing @user.nil? In order to see if the user is there, but it is not acting as I thought:

```
puts @user.inspect
--> #<User id: nil, email: "", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

Why is a user gets created, even though not saved in the DB? How can I make sure that the @user is "nil"? @user.id.nil?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The User record was not saved because it has a blank email (""), so the presence validation fails. You can check the error messages with `@user.errors.full_messages`.

With Active record calling `.create` (or one of its derivatives) will return a new record if the save operation fails (including validations). If you want an Error to be raised when the User record is invalid you can use `.create!`, with a bang(!). I would suggest this newer syntax which is compatible with Rails 4:

```
# Raises an Error if no matching record is found and the new record fails to save.
@user = User.where(:email => params[:email]).first_or_create!

# Does not raise an error if new record fails to save. The returned object will be a new record with post-validation error states.
@user = User.where(:email => params[:email]).first_or_create
```

Which method you choose depends on how you want your application to behave.

Comment: So, how would I check if the @user exists or has been actually created? I don't care if it has been created or is in the DB, but I want to know that is not "nil", so its id is not nil for example?

Comment: `find_or_create` will *always* return a User record, so `@user` will *never* be `nil`. If a User has an id (not nil) then it has been saved to the database. If you want to know if the user is newly created you can use this trick `@user.instance_variable_get(:@new_record_before_save)`.

Comment: Sounds like you might just need a conditional like `if @user && @user.persisted?`

Answer (score 1):

You can ask if it is a new record via:

```
@user.new_record?
```